# Suppress Binary files in VS Code File Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have my C++ folder which have all the C++ codes and their corresponding binary files. I have been looking around to find a way to hide them from the explorer view of VS Code but could not find a suitable pattern as they have no extension.

I tried this in the *settings.json* file, but it hides everything in the folder.

```
    "files.exclude": {
                  "**/*": true,
                  "**/*.cpp": false
}
```

Then I tried this, but it hides both the files.

```
"files.exclude": { 
        "**/*" :{ "when": "$(basename).cpp" }     
    }
```

So I tried this, but it hides the binary files and not the c++ files.

```
"files.exclude": { 
        "**/*.cpp" :{ "when": "$(basename)" }     
    }
```

So I thought swapping the two terms might work.

```
"files.exclude": { 
        "**/$(basename)" :{ "when": "$(basename).cpp" }     
    }
```

But it doesn't work.
If anyone can suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

Well I couldn't find a way to hide only binary files, but I found a workaround:

I edited my tasks.json to save the binary file with .o extension and changed launch.json to open same, then I excluded the .o extension

Added ".o" at this line in my launch.json

```
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.o",
```

Added ".o" here in my tasks.json

```
 "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.o",]
```

Finally changed settings

```
 "files.exclude": {
    "**/*.o": true
},
```

The binary works the same way.

**OPTIONAL:**

Additionally, if you use code-runner, you will have to add .o in the cpp of

> "code-runner.executorMap":

setting

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> "files.exclude": {
>               "**/*": true,
>               "**/*.cpp": false }
> ```

From what I have gathered from this, you want everything out of your way except for the CPP source files. Here is what you can do:

```
"files.exclude": {
     "**/*.{[^.cpp]}*": true
}
```

What you are trying to do is

- hide all files
- then show CPP files.

This does not work. Because, after the first statement there is nothing on the File Explorer list, so your second statement has no effect. What I did is that I joined this two logical statements in one glob so that it basically becomes "Exclude everything but not the CPP files"

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to settings.js works fine for me.

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/*.o": true
},
```